# list of list value assignment incorrectly

Tags: python

When I try to copy a value stored in a list of list to another list of list, Spyder in Anaconda mistakenly assign the value to all lists of the first dimension.

Please see the code below.

I tried to print the value A[0][2] and self.image[2][0] before doing the assignment, they show the correct answer of 0 and 1. But when completing the task of assignment, the address of A[0][2] seems to be read in correctly as A[i][2] for all i.

```
class BImage(object):

    def __init__(self, image):
        self.image = image
        self.d1 = len(image)
        self.d2 = len(image[0]) if len(image) > 0 else 0

    # with a strange bug
    def transp_image(self):
        A = [[0]*self.d1] * self.d2
        for i in range(self.d2):
            for j in range(self.d1):
                # error:
                # when i == 0, j == 2, self.image[2][0] == 1
                # assign the value 1 to A[][2], instead of just A[0][2]
                A[i][j] = self.image[j][i]

        self.image = A
        k = self.d2
        self.d2 = self.d1
        self.d1 = k
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to create your `A` variable.

Consider the following example:

```
lst = [ [float]*2 ]*3
lst[0][0] = 3.14
print(lst)
# [[3.14, <type 'float'>], [3.14, <type 'float'>], [3.14, <type 'float'>]]

lst = [ [float]*2 for _ in range(3) ]
lst[0][0] = 3.14
print(lst)
# [[3.14, <type 'float'>], [<type 'float'>, <type 'float'>], [<type 'float'>, <type 'float'>]]
```

I am sure there are plenty of answers in here who can explain how the first block creates three copies of the same object, whereas the second generates three unique objects.